# FileCopy: File Already Exists - Runtime error '70' Permission Denied'

Tags: excel, error-handling, file-copying, vba

trying to set up an error-handling technique on this bit of code I have.

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim PlanDocTemplate As String
Dim answer1 As String

answer1 = MsgBox("Is this Workbook saved in the appropriate folder?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

If answer1 = vbNo Then
    MsgBox ("Please save this Workbook in the appropriate folder then run again.")
    Exit Sub
Else
    'do nothing
End If

str1 = "C:\user\desktop\document.docx"
PlanDocTemplate = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & Range("A1").Value & ".docx"

Call FileCopy(str1, PlanDocTemplate)
```

Now currently this works fine, but if the user runs the macro once, then again without deleting/renaming the doc that was created from the macro, it results in a Runtime error 70.

Wondering what's the best way to handle this error? Can I have vba ask the user Yes/No "Would you like to delete the original existing document?" No would End the Sub and Yes would delete the original document and continue with the rest of my code.

Thanks all,
Rich

Comment: You can catch and handle the error any way you want, and the way you suggested would probably work fine. Personally I would check the file path in the `FileCopy` sub with something like `If Dir(str1, vbDirectory) = "" Then copy the file Else your msgbox about what to do with the file`. This should prevent you from throwing error in the first place. You should still handle Runtime Error 70 in the event something goes awry.

Comment: Hey Tyeler, Thanks. I wound up using:If Len(Dir(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("A1").Value & ".docx")) = 0 Then ... Else ... Works great. Appreciate it.

Comment: Im glad it worked out for you. FYI using Len(Dir()) = 0 or Dir() = "" will both achieve the same thing.